# Azure kubernetes service (AKS) , load balancer with least Connection

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, azure-aks, kube-proxy, ipvs

I need to make a load balancer that works based on the "Least Connection" , here is the documentation on the Kubernetes website :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/_print/#proxy-mode-ipvs

Look like I need to use IPVS (proxy mode) and then the below option:

```
lc: least connection (smallest number of open connections)
```

but I can't get it done, (I'm using AKS 1.20.7)

**My Question:
How to start the kube-proxy in IPVS proxy mode?**

Comment: IPVS is currently not supported in AKS.  Take a look at this thread for details:   https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1846.

Comment: Thanks @RickRainey , is there anyone to have a loadbalancer that  redirect traffic to the pods with the least live connection in AKS?